# django-notification not sending email by default

Tags: django, django-apps, django-notification

Question,

I have created my NEW notification, my NEW notification templates for it.
Once a user performs a particular action it creates the new record but no email gets sent.

Is django-notification suppose to send automatic emails to the user?

```
def new(request, template_name='wall/new.html', user=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            if request.POST.get('from_user') != request.POST.get('user'):
                if notification:
                    notification.send([request.user], "new_wall_post", {"user": request.user, "post": request.POST.get('text')})
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's supposed to send it automatically.

Try checking:

> 1) That the notification setting for that "new_wall_post" is enabled
>   for that user
>  2) The email is valid for the user
>  3) The user
>   is active
>  4) The email backend is configured correctly

Also, did you mean to send the notification to the wall owner rather than the wall poster?